# How to style/customize a select dropdown in the UC Browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, uc-browser

I have 2 inputs select dropdown who looks perfect in all the main browsers.

I have to make it work with the UC Browser, but I'm stuck with the default appearance of the input that doesn't event respect the `width` applied to it.

I'm asking help because I can't reproduce the bug on desktop. I only see it on the mobile version of the site and I can't inspect my code with any dev tool.

What can I do ? Did anyone had a similar issue ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can emulate each device by clicking F12, then the Toggle Device Mode icon next to search icon in the dev tools (at top of tools). At the top of the browser screen select the device you want and then refresh the page.

Then you should be able to check the elements in the dev tool. It's an awesome resources for figuring out bugs that only certain devices see.

Alternatively you can also "drag up" the bottom bar which has an Emulator tab (drag right of the tabs, not on the tabs) where you can select the device there as well. Each time you change the device just F5 and continue debugging.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't emulate the UC Browser and this is where my bug is.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a simple:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Would do the trick :) !